# Should I use "one" or "it"?

Tags: grammar, pronouns

Which is correct:

> I think I need a better kind of gun. But where can I get **it** from? I can’t find it anywhere in this maze.
>
> I think I need a better kind of gun. But where can I get **one** from? I can’t find one anywhere in this maze.

Comment: I'd leave off the _from_ altogether: _I think I need a better kind of gun. But where can I get one? I can’t find one anywhere in this maze._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy rule: If you're looking for "a" widget, then, use "one". If you're looking for a specific ("the") widget, then "it" is correct.

> I think I need **a** bazooka. The shopkeeper has **one** but I can't afford **it**.

The last "it" is because we're now referring to the shopkeeper's specific bazooka, rather than ones in general.

> I think I need **the** golden bazooka. The shopkeeper has **it** but I can't afford **it**.

Here it's a specific bazooka all the way.

Answer (score 4):

Since you're referring to something non-specific, "one" would be better. If you were referring to a specific object, you would use "it".

> I think I need **the** AK-47. But where can I get it from? I can’t find it anywhere in this maze.

Answer (score 1):

In the context you provided it would appear that "it" is more correct if there is only 1 gun in the maze.  If there is more then one gun "one" might be more correct.  There is not a lot in it though, and both are acceptable.

Comment: davidgo's answer contradicts two previous answers. So now I don't know really know if "it" is acceptable or not in my sentence.